# Disable the new keyboard applet in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, applet

A new keyboard applet is enabled by default in Ubuntu 13.10. I want to disable it and I didn't find any settings to do it. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open System Settings
- Click on the "Text Entry" icon
- Uncheck the box next to **Show current input source in menu bar**

[image]

And that’s it. The switcher is now hidden.

Reference: [Turn new keyboard applet off.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/turn-new-keyboard-applet-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: Click `Text Entry` in the `System Settings`. `Region and Language` is missing in `System Settings`. Then, uncheck the box next to `Show Current Input Source in Menu Bar`.